# Plot from external function to axes matlab GUI

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-figure, axes

I have been trying to get a plot from an external function to an axes inside a GUI. I am **not** using GUIDE. I have tried multiple ways but I keep getting the error

```
Not enough input arguments.

Error in dummyGUI/plotButton_callback (line 19)
    set(hfigure,'CurrentAxes',handles.axes1)
```

Now I have made a dummy GUI and the plot is made in the command window, but I cant get rid off the error.

My code is very simple and as follows:
function dummyGUI

```
f = figure('Name','Name1','Tag','Name1','Units','Pixels','Position',[50 50 1000 600]);

   plotButton = uicontrol('Style', 'pushbutton',...
                         'Parent', f,...
                         'String', 'plot',...
                         'Units', 'pixels', 'Position', [100 400 100 20],...
                         'Callback',@plotButton_callback);

    axes1 = axes('Parent', f,... 
                    'Units', 'pixels', 'Position', [50 50 500 300]);



    function plotButton_callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
        hfigure = getappdata(0,'hfigure');
        axes1 = getappdata(0,'axes1')

        set(hfigure,'CurrentAxes',handles.axes1)

    end
end
```

the code I used in the command window is:

```
x = 1:100;
plot(x,x.^2);
hfigure = gcf;
hfigure = setappdata('0','hfigure')
```

There is something missing obviously, but I have no idea what.

Many thanks in advance.

Romano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way to do it, maybe it is not the correct one but is working. Additional to do that I also found out why I didnt get any plot and any error message. Somehow the variable were not passed in correctly, and where just empty. 
So the variables exist but it didnt contain anything and therefore no error message and no plot.

The way I am doing it right now is.

```
function plotButton_callback(hObject,eventdata,handles)
    set(mainScreen,'CurrentAxes',plotFig);
    [struct] = compare_cycle(var1,var2);
end
```

and compare_cycle.m

```
function [struct] = compare_cycle(var1,x)
     struct = plot(xaxis,yaxis,...)
end
```

please do not care about the names of all the variables, because this is just a tryout.

Thank you for your help Suever.

Answer (score 0):

The immediate issue with your code is that since you aren't using GUIDE, there are only *two* inputs provided to callback functions:

1. The object which triggered the callback
2. The callback event data

The `handles` input is not provided and therefore when you try to access it, MATLAB issues an error about incorrect number of input arguments.

You should either explicitly pass the necessary handles to the callback yourself.

```
set(plotButton, 'Callback', @(src ,evnt)plotButton_callback(src, evnt, axes1))

function plotButtonCallback(hObject, eventdata, axes1)
    hfigure = ancestor(hObject, 'figure');
    set(hfigure, 'CurrentAxes', axes1)
end
```

Or since `plotButtonCallback` is a subfunction of your main function, you can access the `axes1` and `f` variables of the parent function

```
function plotButtonCallback(hObject, eventdata)
    set(f, 'CurrentAxes', axes1)
end
```

**Other Issues**

When you call `setappdata`, you are passing the *string* `'0'` rather than the graphics root object `0`. Also, you need to provide a *third* input to `setappdata` to actually provide the value.

```
setappdata(0, 'hfigure', hfigure)
```

In general, it is a bad idea to save things in the appdata of the root (`0`) object, since if you have two instances of your GUI running, they will interfere with one another.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried this and the error message is gone. However if click on the button it still doesn't show the plot into the axes. For the other issue what do you recommend to do?

Comment: Somebody else have an example or an answer to this? I really need to know how. I have read multiple sites and questions on forums about this topic but I cannot find a clear example or answer. Most explanations are very unclear to me or is it me?

Comment: @Romano where did it plot it instead? You have to put your plotting code in the button callback. I didn't write that part out in my answer

Comment: It doesn't plot anything. What is the benefit of having all the plotting code in an external function if I still need to put the plotting code inside my callback function? Im really sorry, but I am getting really confused now.

Comment: @Romano Your example doesn't show any plotting code... You can easily call *any* function from within your callback